# How to do specific sorting in unix

Tags: shell, sorting, unix

How can I sort following two lines

```
ABCTz.T.3a.B            Student     1       1.4345
ABCTz.T.3.B             Student     1       1.5465
```

to print them like below.

```
ABCTa.T.3.B             Student     1       1.5465
ABCTa.T.3a.B            Student     1       1.4345
```

It can be definitely done using a mixture of sed and sort command but that's not a generic solution.  Here is the sample code,

```
cat 1 | sed "s/\./ ./g" | sort -k3,3 | sed "s/ \././g"
```

This solution requires customization if the length of string changes or number of character changes between two dots(i.e....

```
 ABCTz.T.SC.D.3a.B          Student     1       1.4345
 ABCTz.T.SC.D.3.B           Student     1       1.5465
```

Again, I need to modify the sort expression to consider the length in this case. Looking forward to have something very generic.

Regards, Divesh

Comment: "*Looking forward to have something very generic.*" - Have you considered hiring a programmer?

Comment: hahaha :) Not really. Do we have any better way to do this?

Comment: do you mean the interesting field(`3a, 3`) could be anywhere?

Comment: Thanks Kent. First of all the length of first column can go upto 3-9 worlds( i.e A.B.1.R to Aaac.BBBd.C.D.DC.SC.ABEz.1.R ) so sorting based on field won't be easy.

Comment: You can sort -t"." -k3, specifying the delimiter to use to sort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `version` sort, available with `gnu sort` on first field:

```
sort -V -rk1 file

ABCTz.T.3.B             Student     1       1.5465
ABCTz.T.3a.B            Student     1       1.4345
```

Comment: Above example was just a snippet of my input file so reversing the order won't do any good. thanks

Comment: Show better sample data in that case

Answer (score 0):

If the format is based on tabs, it's easy.

```
cat 1|sort -t"[Control-V][TAB]" -n -r -k4
```

But if the number of spaces is variable, I sort with awk.

This formula will put the 4th field at the beginning, followed by |, then it will sort based on this field, and then will strip it out:

```
cat 1|awk '{print $4 "|" $0}' |sort -t"|" -n -r -k1|cut -d"|" -f2-
```

Example:

```
boxes@osboxes Desktop]$ cat 1
asdfa    safadf     1.2
asldfkañ  sdlfsld      1.3
[osboxes@osboxes Desktop]$ cat 1 | awk '{print $3 "|" $0}'|sort -t"|" -n -r     -k1|cut -d"|" -f2-
asldfkañ  sdlfsld      1.3
asdfa    safadf     1.2
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks Jose. It's not helpful.

Comment: Why not? Can you explain better the question?